# Apache Spark Maven Dependencies for release and develop an app

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I have to follow [this](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html) tutorial to create a uber jar for my Apache Spark application with maven.

I have set all Spark Dependencies in the pom with `<scope>provided</scope>`.
This works very well, but now when I run the application locally, I get an error for missing Spark dependencies.

At the moment I had to remove `provided` tag from the pom.

How can I make provided spark dependencies only when building app for release?

I use Intellij as IDE for developing applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create seperate Maven profiles.

Best option is to have dependencyManagment section in POM where you'll specify versions, then in profiles you will have only groupId + artifactId + scope

For example:

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Here Spark deps without provided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Here Spark deps with provided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```